# Install4j auto-update - Using the Update Schedule Registry

Tags: java, installation, install4j

I am trying to use install4j's auto-update feature, using the "Updater with silent version check". I have the auto-update working fine if I force the schedule to be Always, or every launch. The problem I am having is with the update schedule.

I have added a Configurable Form just before my installation action. On this form is an Update Schedule Selector. In my Updater with silent version check on the launcher integration page I have set the launch schedule to "According to update schedule registry" (If this is set to always the auto-update works).

So now when running through the installation you get prompted with the form to set your update schedule, but setting to "On every start" or anything else for that matter seems to not work. My program does not seem to do the Update check at all while using the registry.

My thought is that the Configurable Form I have created is not updating the Update Schedule. I imagine I may need to be calling UpdateScheduleRegistry.setUpdateSchedule(UpdateSchedule), but I am not sure what to be passing through as the Update Schedule Selector form component doesn't have a variable assigned to it. I would also think that I would need to call this in the post-activation script.

Anyone have ideas that can help me get this up and running?

Thanks,
Shayne

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble finding this setting on Windows for our application.

After further investigation the registry value is actually stored in:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ej-technologies\install4j\installations

Just wanted to note it here in case anyone else comes across this same question or issue.

Answer (score 0):

The "Update schedule selector" saves the update schedule automatically.

Check the registry key

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ej-technologies\install4j\installations

There should be a value

updateSchedule[application ID]

in it with a verbose value.